# Canvas drawImage is slow on large source

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm making a game and are creating a camera to follow the player. I've got a large canvas (game map) of 4096x4096px. For this I would like to draw only a portion of this with:

```
ctx.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 4096, 4096 );
```

Before each frame I will call:

```
ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 800, 600 );
```

To only clear the camera. What I can see is that drawImage is super slow, performance wise. Is my game map to large and that is not handled by drawImage? How do I create a smooth rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding some arguments of `drawImage`.

As you've written `drawImage`, it will clip an 800x600 from the source. Then it will enlarge it to 4096x4096. And it will finally draw that 4096x4096 on the canvas.

So you have a 4096x4096 spritesheet. You want to clip a 800x600 part from that spritesheet and draw that clipping to canvas:

```
// this will clip 800x600px from your source image
// starting at top-left == [1600,0]
// and it will paint that clipping at [0,0] on the canvas
// while not changing the clipping size from its original 800x600

ctx.drawImage(
    yourImage        // use yourImage as the source image
    1600,0           // clip from the source image with top-left at [1600,0]
    800,600          // clip 800x600px from the source
    0,0              // paint the clipping at [0,0] on the canvas
    800,600          // use the same 800x600 size that was clipped
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see more code to really know where the performance issues are.

Most likely it is the size that is slowing you down. `drawImage()` is [easily the fastest method](http://jsperf.com/canvas-drawimage-vs-putimagedata/21) for updating the canvas but there are other things which can slow you down a lot such as use of `getImageData()` or inefficient Javascript.